# Bootstrap scrollspy flicking between sections

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a subnav style Bootstrap scrollspy on my page but odd things seem to be happening. I have four sections, each in a div with I have given an id to. However, when either clicking on the link or scrolling, it is jumping to odd places.

It can be viewed here.
http://www.writeupp.com/faq.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having similar problems. For some reason when adding tabs inside the area that scrollspy is looking in it causes it to break. Any ideas anyone? Here is the link to where I am experiencing the problem: http://landornewyork.com/diageo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar issue that you speak of. Where the top nav flickers when I scrolled. I realized that it was because I had tabbable content on the page. My fix to this was to add data-target=".navbar" to my body element in addition to the data-spy="scroll" so that scrollspy knows which navigation bar to alter. I hope this helps.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that when using `scrollspy` in older versions of IE - if your `anchor`s are pointing to html5 elements, e.g. `section`, your `.nav` will flicker between the first 2 `anchors` in the `ul`.  This is because jquery can't figure out the position of these 'foreign' DOM elements.  To fix this either use `div`s instead of `section`s or use `modernizr.js` (specifically the `html5shiv` component).

Check the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) site for more info.